# How to assign a blob to an image src using angular

Tags: angular

I am fetching an image via a http request which returns a blob and i want to assign the blob returned to an image src.

**http request:**

```
   const options = {
        headers,
        responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
    };

    return this.httpClient.get(url, options)
```

**component.ts**

```
async ngOnInit() {
   this.frontImageSrc = getImage()
}

async getImage() {
    const image = await this.service.imageRequest(id, "front", token).toPromise();
    var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(image)
    return imageUrl
}
```

**component.html**

```
  <img src={{frontImageSrc}} alt="image"/>
```

The image src does not get assigned and in the console i can see the following.

> blob:http://localhost:4200/f846a3aa-8cd3-4876-8dd3-972c9469feb2
>   14:00:00.664
>   unsafe:blob:http://localhost:4200/f846a3aa-8cd3-4876-8dd3-972c9469feb2:1
>   GET
>   unsafe:blob:http://localhost:4200/f846a3aa-8cd3-4876-8dd3-972c9469feb2
>   net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Are you getting proper response from the API?

Comment: I think issue is that angular sanitizes your link, you can use `Sanitzer` and `bypassSecurity` to see if it works. Also it's better to use property binding instead of binding literal like `[src]="frontImageSrc"`. Besides that don't forget to revoke your blob url in `ngOnDestroy`. If this works I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @Arcteezy Yes i am

Comment: @BlindDespair Can you post an answer with the use of Sanitizer bypassSecurity, i don't know how they work.

Comment: done, hope it helps you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Message about `:unsafe` stuff means that angular sanitised your url, because it considers it unsafe. Cleanest way to work this around is to introduce a pipe (although it is not necessary): like so:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeResourceUrl' })
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private readonly sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public transform(url: string): SafeResourceUrl {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

Then in your component you can the following:

**component.html**

```
  <img [src]="frontImageSrc | safeResourceUrl" alt="image"/>
```

**component.ts**

```
async ngOnInit() {
   this.frontImageSrc = getImage()
}

async getImage() {
    const image = await this.service.imageRequest(id, "front", token).toPromise();
    var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(image)
    return imageUrl
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  URL.revokeObjectURL(this.imageUrl)
}
```

Of course you can do bypassing in your `ngOnInit` instead, but it's cleaner to use pipe. Also since url is created asynchronously it might make sense to do a null check in the template.

Comment: This works great! I am trying to use the "angular-x-image-viewer" component to display the image. This component takes an array of strings as source [src]. How can be applied the pipe in this case? I dont know how the html syntax would look like.

Comment: @RickyTad in case you need an array, you need to bypass security for each item in it, you can extend pipe to accept array or 1 string and if it's array then map it. or you can just do this on component level